# Using PHP and MongoDB sorting results based on key AND value?

Tags: php, sorting, mongodb, mapreduce

For my case i am using MongoDB to store a whole bunch of products from 50 countries, entry in DB looks something like this:

```
{
    _id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    country: 'au',
    title: 'Equipment X',
    price: 1000,
},
{
    _id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxy,
    country: 'us',
    title: 'Equipment Y',
    price: 1000,
},
...
...
```

I would like to know if it is at all possible to query all products and sort by country from **au** FIRST, then the rest of the products after that. The simple MongoDB sort seems to only sort by key. If it is possible, does it involve map/reduce?

**Edit: A more detailed example**

Documents in collection:

```
{ country:'cn', title:'Equipment A', price:'100'},
{ country:'au', title:'Equipment B', price:'100'},
{ country:'za', title:'Equipment C', price:'100'},
{ country:'us', title:'Equipment D', price:'100'},
{ country:'nz', title:'Equipment E', price:'100'},
{ country:'it', title:'Equipment F', price:'100'},
{ country:'nz', title:'Equipment G', price:'100'},
{ country:'au', title:'Equipment H', price:'100'},
```

I am looking for a sort that will return products from **nz** to be at the top and then follow by all other products, like this:

```
{ country:'nz', title:'Equipment E', price:'100'},
{ country:'nz', title:'Equipment G', price:'100'},
{ country:'au', title:'Equipment B', price:'100'},
{ country:'au', title:'Equipment H', price:'100'},
{ country:'cn', title:'Equipment A', price:'100'},
{ country:'it', title:'Equipment F', price:'100'},
{ country:'us', title:'Equipment D', price:'100'},
{ country:'za', title:'Equipment C', price:'100'},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By sorting on a key, it means sorting on the values in a key. This is what you want, I think. (Left off the beginning part to connect to the db and pick a collection).

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->sort(array('country' => 1))
```

**update** So is this what you want to do?

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('country' => 'nz'));
// process your nz products...

$cursor = $collection->find(array('country' => array( '$neq' => 'nz' )));
// process the rest of your products...
```

**update2** Well, I think you may need to resort to doing something like this, if you really need this functionality.

```
// create a new field on the records that don't have it yet
$collection->update(
   array('country' => 'nz', array('first' => array('$exists' => false))), 
   array('$set' => array('first'=>1)), 
   array('multiple' => true));
// ensure index on that field
$collection->ensureIndex(array('first' => 1));
// find everything
$cursor = $collection->find();
// sort on that field
$cursor->sort(array('first':-1));
```

Comment: Hi there! That will only sort the country alphabetically. If i would like to sort it to have products from **nz** first, then the rest will follow after, it won't work with just key sorting.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do. Why can't you just do two queries, if you want to prioritize on a country. Or you could have another key/value called "countryOrder:0" for NZ, and then, where you specify the real order you want countries to appear.

Comment: Two queries will require me to stitch the results together, and i lose out on using `skip()` and `limit()` for paging purposes. I've just edited the question to have a more detailed(?) example. Sorry, having a tough time explaining what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes i think so too, definitely one of the possible options. Its not that messy either, i.e. i wont be adding 30 new properties for each document to denote 30 countries, just 1 extra on each. Thanks @WesFreeman for the help!

Comment: You only really need to add the extra property on the nz documents--the rest don't need it at all. And you can do it incrementally and update them en masse. It's not too bad, but a bit more messy than you might like. It's probably faster than the aggregation stuff coming out, though--once the "first" field is there the update won't be doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

> The simple MongoDB sort seems to only sort by key

Truly uninformed nonsense.

MongoDB can sort by multiple criteria. A simple look at the basic 
sorting documentation would have been useful here.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order

Comment: multiple key yes, not value, yet. I understand you can sort by something like {country:1, title:1} and it will come back with the sorting with that order. What i am looking for is sorting like {country:"au", title:1}. Not possible at this point but possibly in next mongo release. [http://blog.mongodb.org/post/16015854270/operations-in-the-new-aggregation-framework]